# NoSuchElementException while trying click on a pop up's button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner at Selenium + Java and I am trying to build my framework with this page: http://automationpractice.com/index.php. I've created some basic test cases like login and register. Now I am trying to make some cases of adding a product to the cart. There are two ways to do that:

1. Hover on a product then click on  button
2. Click on overview of product then click on  button

I am having some troubles:

1. I tried

   ```
   Actions action = new Actions(ldriver);
   action.moveToElement(addToCartButton).build().perform();
   ```

   but that didn't work for me. This method is clicking on the element not hovering it.
2. I'm having trouble with the pop up window. I am getting a `NoSuchElementException` while trying to click on the button in the popup. I guess that popup is opening at a new url. I was trying a method with windowHandle and it didn't work at all.

Any ideas to resolve my problem?

Comment: Please add the HTML to your question for the two buttons, the hover one and the popup one. Please add the code for your second attempt. The code you posted for the first attempt isn't clicking anything, it's just hovering. You'll have to add more code or debug yourself to see where the click is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default" href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=cart&amp;add=1&amp;id_product=2&amp;token=0a604ce6a643bdbc33ab020a4672ec30" rel="nofollow" title="Add to cart" data-id-product="2">
                                    <span>Add to cart</span>
                                </a>
```

This is code for hovering on product.

```
<p id="add_to_cart" class="buttons_bottom_block no-print">
                            <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="exclusive">
                                <span>Add to cart</span>
                            </button>
                        </p>
```

And this above is for pop up.

```
    public void hoverOnProduct ()
{
    Actions action = new Actions(ldriver);
    action.moveToElement(productWindow).build().perform();

}

public void clickProductImage ()
{
    productImage.click();
}

public void clickAddtoCartButton ()
{
    ldriver.switchTo().activeElement().submit();
    addToCartButton.click();
}
```

I Was trying theese methods.